# Error in deploy a project on Glassfish:No qualifying bean of type [com.karans.webstore.models.Daoimp.UserDAOimp] found for dependency

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, glassfish

I want to write a simple Web Store in NetBeans in Spring MVC framework. But when I deploy my program on Glassfish, this Error occurred:

```
Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.karans.webstore.models.Daoimp.UserDAOimp] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}. Please see server.log for more details`.
```

My pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.karans</groupId>
    <artifactId>webstore</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>webstore</name>
<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- spring-context which provides core functionality -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- The spring-aop module provides an AOP Alliance-compliant aspect-oriented 
    programming implementation allowing you to define -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- The spring-webmvc module (also known as the Web-Servlet module) contains 
    Spring’s model-view-controller (MVC) and REST Web Services implementation 
    for web applications -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- The spring-web module provides basic web-oriented integration features 
    such as multipart file upload functionality and the initialization of the 
    IoC container using Servlet listeners and a web-oriented application context -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSTL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My web.xml is:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/Spring-Datasource.xml</param-value>    <!-- This setup "A" works -->
    <!-- <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/hibernate-context.xml</param-value> -->       <!-- Once the commented sections are shifted, this setup "B" fails -->
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.karans.webstore.*" /> 


<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Spring-Datasource.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="ds"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webstore" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="123456" />
</bean>


<bean id="jt" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">  
    <property name="dataSource" ref="ds"></property>  
</bean>  


<bean id="ProductDAOimpl" class="com.karans.webstore.models.Daoimp.ProductDAOimp">

    <property name="template" ref="jt"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="UserDAOimpl"    class="com.karans.webstore.models.Daoimp.UserDAOimp">

    <property name="template" ref="jt"></property>  
</bean>
<bean id="CartDAOimpl" class="com.karans.webstore.models.Daoimp.CartDAOimp">

    <property name="template" ref="jt"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="usercontroller" class="com.karans.webstore.controllers.userController">

    <property name="userdaoimp" ref="UserDAOimp"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="productcontroller" class="com.karans.webstore.controllers.productController">

    <property name="ProductDaoimp" ref="ProductDAOimp"></property>
</bean>
```

UserDAOimp:

```
package com.karans.webstore.models.Daoimp;

import com.karans.webstore.models.Dao.UserDAO;
import com.karans.webstore.models.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;



import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

public class UserDAOimp  implements UserDAO{
@Autowired


 JdbcTemplate template;
@Override
public User GetUsertByUsername(String username, String password) {
    User user=null;
    String sql = "select * from user where username=? AND password=?";
  user=(User) template.queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{username ,password},new BeanPropertyRowMapper(User.class));
    return  user;
}

}
```

And other classes is like this.
UserDAO:

```
package com.karans.webstore.models.Dao;

import com.karans.webstore.models.User;


public interface UserDAO {
public User GetUsertByUsername(String username,String password); 


}
```

User:

```
package com.karans.webstore.models;
public class User {



private int iduser;;
   private String username;
   private String password;

public void setIduser(int iduser) {
    this.iduser = iduser;
}

public int getIduser() {
    return iduser;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}


}
```

userController:

```
package com.karans.webstore.controllers;
import com.karans.webstore.models.Daoimp.UserDAOimp;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
@Controller
public class userController {
@Autowired
UserDAOimp userdaoimp;
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public String login(){


    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping( value="/loginfailed", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginError(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("error", "true");
    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping( value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String logout(Model model){
    return "login";
}   
}
```

And so on.
How can fix the problem?

Comment: I think that the problem can be in web.xml or mvc-dispatcher.xml, because when I deleted this part of xml:
<context:component-scan base-package="com.karans.webstore.*" /> 
that error went. In fact I think this tag could be incorrect. because all my beans id defined in Spring-Datasource.xml, not in my classes.

Comment: Not a spring user, but it looks like you may have given your Beans incorrect IDs. You have set the id to be `UserDAOimpl` but Spring is looking for `UserDAOimp`.

Comment: I used @Autowired annotation , so its default is getByName not getById, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Add the context-listener to web.xml in order to spring load the contextConfigLocation:

```
 <listener> 
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoade‌​rListener</listener-‌​class> 
 </listener>
```

Also you can try changing the web.xml file and remove the context-param section of web.xml and set the Spring-Datasource.xml as init-param to dispatcher servlet like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/Spring-Datasource.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Comment: It isn't a dispatcher to set as dispatcher.

Comment: in that case add a contex listener to the web.xml like this   <listener>
     <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>